# express route beginning with?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I'm trying to create a route that begins with a question mark and I cannot get it done. This is what I have:

```
app.get('/?email=:e', function(req, res){
    console.log("here");
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I'm trying to have the user enter something that will be 'e' and the route be '/?email='.

Am I dong it correctly? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I believe your route should just be `'/'` and the `email` parameter can be retrieved from `req.query`

Comment: Alternatively, your route can be `/email` and whatever parameters you send with your `get` request will be in `req.query`.

Comment: So instead I should do something like :                              app.get('/email=:e', function(req, res){
    console.log("here");
    console.log(req.query);
});

Comment: You can just do `app.get('/email', function(req, res){ console.log("here"); console.log(req.query); });` and whatever `get` parameters you send to the `/email` endpoint should be in `req.query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying something like `http://localhost:3000/?email=abc@example.com` then the function should be

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("email is " + req.query.email);
});
```

If you want to send email in your path something like `http://localhost:3000/email/abc@example.com` then you may try

```
app.get('/email/:email', function(req, res){
    console.log("email is " + req.params.email);
});
```

or `email` path with `e` query string something like `http://localhost:3000/email?e=abc@example.com`

```
app.get('/email', function(req, res){
    console.log("email is " + req.query.e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well api routing doesn't allow ? in the url, because it would automatically be resolved as a query parameter.